# Rails generate destroy [rails-generator] or [rails-generate]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

What difference, if any, is there between the Ruby on Rails tags [rails-generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails-generator) and [rails-generate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails-generate)? Should one of them be merged into the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No difference. The command `rails generate` runs "Rails generator" that is used to generate templates for new files such as new models or database migrations.